# Nested for loops in C language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

An abundant number is a natural number that is less than the sum of its proper divisors. For example `12 < 1+2+3+4+6=16` so 12 is an abundant number, while `16 > 1+2+4+8=15` is not an abundant number. 
I have to write a program in C language so that for the input k, the output are all abundant numbers less than or equal to k.

I'm only a beginner at this so what I first wanted to do is to write a program that will check whether k is abundant or not. So this is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int k, i, s = 0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        if (k % i == 0)
            s = s + i;
    }
    if (k < s)
        printf("%d" is an abundant number", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ignore this above, I only wanted to show you I actually tried something by myself. Now I wasn't sure how to make this program list the abundant numbers that are also less than `k`, but I found the solution which I don't understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int k, i, j, s;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        s = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                s = s + j:
        }
        if (i < s)
            printf("%d"\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused by this nested for loop, can someone explain exactly how it works? For instance if we put k=18, what exactly happens with this for loops so that in the end we get 12 and 18 as output?

Comment: `s=s+j:` - this looks completely broken

Comment: The outer loop goes from 1 to 18 including. so the inner loop looks like this: `for(j=1; j<1; j++)`  for the first time. then it goes to `for(j=1; j<2; j++)` and then `for(j=1; j<3; j++)` after a while it will get to `for(j=1; j<12; j++)` and `for(j=1; j<18; j++)` Try to run it on paper.

Comment: Everything inside your first for loop works like the program that you wrote to check if number is abundant or not. And this for loop runs this code for values of i from 1 to 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to step through the code manually and write down the line number of the executing code and how the variables change.

Like

```
L01:    int k,i,j,s;                // k=?, i=?, j=?, s=?
L02:    scanf("%d", &k);            // k=18, i=?, j=?, s=?
L03:    for(i=1;                    // k=18, i=1, j=?, s=?
L03:             i<=k;              // TRUE
L04:        s=0;                    // k=18, i=1, j=?, s=0
L05:        for(j=1;                // k=18, i=1, j=1, s=0
L05:                 j<i;           // FALSE
L03:                      i++)      // k=18, i=2, j=1, s=0
L03:             i<=k;              // TRUE
L04:        s=0;                    // k=18, i=2, j=1, s=0
L05:        for(j=1;                // k=18, i=2, j=1, s=0
L05:                 j<i;           // TRUE
L06:            if(i%j==0)          // TRUE
L07:                s=s+j:          // k=18, i=2, j=1, s=1
L05:                      j++)      // k=18, i=2, j=2, s=0
L05:                  j<i;          // FALSE
and so on ....
```

I takes quite some time but you should soon see the pattern and there by understand how for-loops works.

Another thing that might help you understanding for-loops are to realize that

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    code...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
i=0;
while (i<N)
{
    code...

     i++;
}
```

**BTW:**

Always check the return value from `scanf` - like:

```
if (scanf("%d", &k) != 1)
{
    printf("Input error! Program terminates.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: In the inner loop when if(i%j==0) is false, then we go back to the outer loop? For example, when i=3 and j=2, 3%2==0 is false, so after that we take i=4 and j=2?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely - No, the code `if (i%j==0)` is not part of the loops terminate-condition - it's rather the code in the loop-body. When `(i%j==0)` is false, the next statement will be `j++` and then it will be `j < i;` (which may or may no terminate the inner-loop)

Comment: And when j<i is false, then the next statement is i++? 
Also, can you tell me when I get to the point when i=12, what should be j and s?

Answer (score 0):

the inner loop is executed k time;

1. when i=1 nothing happens
2. when i=2 the inner loop checks if 2 is abundant or not
3. when i=3 the inner loop checks if 3 is abundant or not

and so on. Maybe it would be better to rewrite your code so that variable names explains its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simpler implementation. This is same as your own attempt. just that it is enough to run till k/2 instead of k-1

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(void) {

        int k,i,j,s;
        scanf("%d", &k);
        s=0;
        for(i=1; i<=(k/2); i++) { //running till half of the entered value is sufficient
            if(k%i == 0)
            {
                s+=i;  //if it is a divisor add it to the sum
            }
        }
        printf("sum is %d\n\r",s);
        if(k<s)
           printf("%d is abundant\n\r",k);
        else
           printf("%d is not abundant\n\r",k);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) {

int upper_limit,candidate,divisor,s;

scanf("%d", &upper_limit); 

for(candidate=1; candidate<=upper_limit; candidate++) {

    s=0; 

    for(divisor=1; divisor<=(candidate/2); divisor++) {

        if((candidate%divisor)==0) 

            s=s+divisor:
    }

if(candidate<s) 
    printf("%d"\n", candidate);

}

return 0;

}
```